# 'Open' - undeclared identifier

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

Does somebody know why this code inside a **`.mqh`** file throws the error **`'Open' - undeclared identifier`**?

It seems like `Open`, `Close`, `High`, `Low` functions aren´t "detected" in my library. ( Other system functions like `Print()` are properly loaded ).

```
bool isBlueCandle( int candle ) export {
   return Open[candle] < Close[candle];
}
```

Comment: Welcome, webmeiker. Would you mind to post the complete context of your code? After about a decade, MT4 started to become a moving sands territory, so kindly review all the compilation landscape - #property settings, #include(s) and strict/non-strict language options and a Build 84x version of the MetaLang.exe ( yes, "New"-MQL4.56789 is a beast to be carefull to work with :o) just remind how many times in the last year opening of an MQ4 code started a Help update ( == another "New"-syntax revision ... ( not speaking about shocks alike **`string`**-s not being `string`, but a **`struct`(!!)**))

Comment: Good to know the situation works for you, webmeiker :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not exactly, neither 1:1 copy, nor any MODs, return any error:

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|  isBlueCandle TESTs                     MetaLang.exe: Build 1154 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool isBlueCANDLE_TEST(        int candle ) export
{
   return Open[candle] < Close[candle];
}

bool isBlueCANDLE_TEST2(       int candle ) export {
   return Open[candle] < Close[candle];
}

bool isBlueCANDLE_TEST3( const int candle ) export {
   return Open[candle] < Close[candle];
}

bool isBlueCANDLE_TEST4( const int candle ) export {
   return( Open[candle] < Close[candle] );
}
```

As posted in the comment above, the missing context would help trace the root-cause for your stated issue.

Post a complete copy of the MetaLang.exe Error-description.
Use mouse-right-click + copy ( in MetaLang.exe-Toolbox window on [Error]-page  + paste that complete description on StackOverflow )

*As an example:*

```
return value of 'OrderModify' should be checked
FOREX_SimpleSAR_EA_msMOD_0.00.mq4   227 19
```

### Just for a clarity sake:

**`MQL4`** recognises both functions ( `Print()` ) and other objects ( `Open` ) with specific access-protocol to work with them. In case of functions, one passes "arguments" compatible with the function´s expectations.

`Open`, `High`, `Volume` et al, are not functions, but **Arrays**, the more, these arrays are special and carefully constructed in the internal MT4-engine, so as to provide a very fast & very efficient manipulation.

MetaQuotes call this a **TimeSeries**-object, a reversed-stepping-index into 
( otherwise normal ) array.

So, your function **`isBlueCandle()`** is indeed a function, however, internally it does not call a function, but it compares a cell-values of **`Open`** ( the `[anIntIndexAsPtrIntoTimeSeriesOrderedARRAY]`-*referenced  cell )
against a value of  **`Close`** ( namely the `[anIntIndexAsPtrIntoTimeSeriesOrderedARRAY]`-*referenced cell ) to construct a **`bool`** which the **`isBlueCandle()`** function is about to return.

Comment: @webmeiker would you consider the answer as accepted?